# handing qwidget.winid to DLL in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, hwnd

I have a dll, which use OpenGl to draw on window. Dll get window by HWMD.

DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Init(HWND hWnd);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Resize(HWND hWnd, int w, int h);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Paint(HWND hWnd);
```

The c++ qt application is work properly.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QLibrary>

typedef void (*InitPrototype)(HWND);
typedef void (*PaintPrototype)(HWND);
typedef void (*ResizePrototype)(HWND, int, int);

InitPrototype c_Init;
PaintPrototype c_Paint;
ResizePrototype c_Resize;

bool load_opengl_library(){
    QLibrary lib("engine3d");
    lib.load();
    c_Init = (InitPrototype)lib.resolve("Init");
    c_Paint = (PaintPrototype)lib.resolve("Paint");
    c_Resize = (ResizePrototype)lib.resolve("Resize");
    return true;
}

class MyGlWidget: public QGLWidget {
public:
    MyGlWidget(QWidget *parent = 0): QGLWidget(parent){}
    void showEvent(QShowEvent* event){
        c_Init((HWND)(this->winId()));
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event){
        c_Paint((HWND)this->winId());
    }
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event){
        c_Resize((HWND)this->winId(), this->width(), this->height());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    load_opengl_library();
    MyGlWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But how do the same in python? My program crushes on sending widget.winId().

```
# coding=utf-8
import ctypes
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtOpenGL
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

e3d = ctypes.CDLL(r"engine3d.dll")
init = lambda hwnd: e3d.Init(hwnd)
paint = lambda hwnd: e3d.Paint(hwnd)
resize = lambda hwnd, w, h: e3d.Paint(hwnd, w, h)

class MyGLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def showEvent(self, ev):
        init(self.winId())
    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        paint(self.winId())
    def resizeEvent(self, ev):
        resize(self.winId(), self.width(), self.height())

w = MyGLWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

print(self.winId()) is

Comment: `In: print(self.winId())
     Out: <sip.voidptr object at 0x03463C38>`

Comment: Answer: `init = e3d.Init
init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32]
paint = e3d.Paint
paint.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32]
resize = e3d.Resize
resize.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be easier to check having the dll, so I'll speak out the blue. In your c++ code you got this initialization code:

```
bool load_opengl_library(){
    QLibrary lib("engine3d");
    lib.load();
    c_Init = (InitPrototype)lib.resolve("Init");
    c_Paint = (PaintPrototype)lib.resolve("Paint");
    c_Resize = (ResizePrototype)lib.resolve("Resize");
    return true;
}

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    load_opengl_library();
    MyGlWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Where you create your engine instance `lib`and using `load`method but in python you're not doing anything of that:

```
w = MyGLWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

But before creating the `MyGLWidget` you're not initializing your engine as its c++ counterpart, question is, why not?

Comment: I thought that it initialized by ctypes.For example for project https://github.com/ombschervister/ctypes_test this work for default types.
But when i try to send HWND i catch exception `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1`

Comment: Yes, you was right. I have defined the types of functions and program is working now.  HWND is ctypes.c_uint32.

Comment: @den Btw, it's quite interesting approach abstracting the whole game engine in c++ and using pyqt as a frontend. Do you have any working example on github to take a look of it?

Comment: @den Cool, I see is on early stage. One little advice though, If you know about something that looks like glBegin(), forget it! Just use **modern OpenGL** (OpenGL 3 and 4) ;-)